# How to use Ramda's sortBy function to sort an array of objects based on a nested property

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I am practicing [ramda](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#sortBy).I have an array of objects that have a nested property children. I want to sort the array based on which object has the most children using Ramda's sortBy function.

Here's an example array:

```js
[
  {
    "name": "Felicia",
    "age": "60",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Adrian",
        "age": "4"
      },
      {
        "name": "Joseph",
        "age": "5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Alicia",
    "age": "43",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Billy",
        "age": "3"
      },
      {
        "name": "Mary",
        "age": "8"
      },
     {
        "name": "john",
        "age": "12"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `R.sortWith`, get the children's length, and use `R.descend` to sort from highest to lowest:

```js
const { sortWith, descend, path } = R

const fn = sortWith([
  descend(path(['children', 'length'])) // or descend(pipe(prop('children'), length))
])

const arr = [{"name":"Felicia","age":"60","children":[{"name":"Adrian","age":"4"},{"name":"Joseph","age":"5"}]},{"name":"Alicia","age":"43","children":[{"name":"Billy","age":"3"},{"name":"Mary","age":"8"},{"name":"john","age":"12"}]}]

const result = fn(arr)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: The function already exists in the app, I need to modify it and add sort logic based on highest to lowest cartItems length.

Comment: It works with TS out of the box as long as you include the latest @types/ramda. See sandbox here - https://codesandbox.io/s/ramda-ts-sortwith-02hmlm.